# mongoDB remote connection is not working with new VM on azure where its working on VM classic

Tags: mongodb, azure, azure-virtual-machine

I have new VM and old VM(classic) both in my azure account. I want to install mongoDB in my new VM for database hosting. I have installed the mongoDB in my VM, created inbound rules from firewall, created inbound rules from azure new VM networ security portal but its still not working. i am not able to connect to my mongoDB from my local machine. However its working locally on VM.

i have applied same settings in Classic VM and its working smoothly. But i want to go ahead with the new VM only.

Please check this image to validate the inbound settings

### Inbound settings screenshot

[image: Inbound settings screenshot]

Comment: Please edit your question to show your inbound rules. Otherwise, there's really no way to validate whether those settings are correct. (also this really belongs on ServerFault, not StackOverflow).

Comment: Hi Check attached image now